# unable to view data using $scope in angularjs

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, angularjs-scope

I am trying to get data from cordova sqlite and add it to the scope. and bind the data in the view page.but i get error "cannot read push of undefined".and no data shows in the view page.

//My controller

```
$scope.codesubmit=function(data){
      var query = "SELECT * FROM item_master WHERE menucode = ?";
      $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [data.menucode]).then(function (res) {
        alert("inside success");
 $scope.items.push({"menucode":"+res.rows.item(0).menucode+","menuname":"+res.rows.item(0).menuname+","quantity":"+data.quantity+","price":"+res.rows.item(0).price+"});
           alert(items);
    },function (err) {
              console.error(err);
            });
```

//My view page

```
<tbody id=Tabledata>
           <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
             <td>{{item.menucode}}</td>
             <td>{{item.menuname}}</td>
             <td>{{data.quantity}}</td>
             <td>{{item.price}}</td>
             <td>{{total}}</td>
             <td><a class='delete' href='#' ng-click()id='"+res.rows.item(0).id+"'>Delete</a></td>
           </tr>
         </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to define $scope.items array before you start using it.

```
$scope.codesubmit=function(data){
$scope.items = [];   //define the array here
  var query = "SELECT * FROM item_master WHERE menucode = ?";
  $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [data.menucode]).then(function (res) {
    alert("inside success");
 $scope.items.push({menucode: res.rows.item(0).menucode, menuname: res.rows.item(0).menuname,quantity: data.quantity, price: res.rows.item(0).price});
       alert(items);
},function (err) {
          console.error(err);
        });
```

adding `$scope.items = [];` at the beginning of your function definition will create an empty array which you can populate by the data retrieved from the database. you can also define it globally as well if you want to access it somewhere else.

Comment: thanks for the answer. i got it but ""menucode":"+res.rows.item(0).menucode+"" this line returns ""+res.rows.item(0).menucode+"".how to get the value i.e. menucode..

Comment: put your code `res.rows.item(0).menucode` outside double quotes. Everything that is inside is treated as as a string.  Also i am not sure why do you even need `+` sign. i have edited my answer accordingly. plz give it a try. Happy to help :)

Comment: items[] array contains data that is shown in a table.how to get all data of the table and store it in sqlite database.till now i have tried $scope.addsaleandsaledetails=function(){
  console.log($scope.items);
   var index = 0;
        $scope.items.forEach(function (item) {
            console.log('item #' + (index++) + ': ' + JSON.stringify(item));
});
}

Comment: i think you will have to execute insert query of each row of $scope.items . Your approach looks fine to me. is there any problem you are facing?

Comment: i dont get any data in console.it only shows [].I think I am unable to get items.once i get the items that are available in the table .then i ll execute insert query.

Comment: check if $scope.items is not empty by writing console.log($scope.item.length). I cannot make any comment without looking at your code

Comment: i get length=0  //this is my view     <tbody id=Tabledata>
           <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
             <td ng-model="item.price">{{item.price}}</td>
             <td ng-model="item.total">{{item.total}}</td>     //tyhis is my controller     $scope.addsaleandsaledetails=function(){
  console.log($scope.items.length);
   var index = 0;
        $scope.items.forEach(function (item) {
            console.log('item #' + (index++) + ': ' + JSON.stringify(item));
});
}

Comment: First, `ng-model="item.price"` means you should have a variable $scope.item.price in your controller which is not there. Second, if you are able to populate your table row with the data present in $scope.items and still your are getting `$scope.items.length` as 0 then somewhere in your controller you must have written `$scope.items = [];` before calling the function `$scope.addsalesandsaledeatils`. that is the reason you are getting empty array. either remove that line or try storing its value in some another variable and use the new variable in your function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37322467/get-all-row-data-from-dynamically-created-table-in-angularjs               please check this

Answer (score 0):

it seems $scope.items is undefined. Define your $scope.items object first.

```
$scope.items = [];
```

Comment: adding this line before push will empty the array before every push hence the array will contain only the current element

Comment: Actually I just want to say define $scope.items object before the process. Yes it would be better if he can add this line as a global variable or something like that.